# Exec returning blank array

Tags: php, exec

I've seen more than a few questions on this whilst searching, but none with a working answer, just recommendations of other things to try

```
$server = "IPADDRESS";
$username = "USER";
$port = "22";
$ftpuser = "FTPUSER"
$ftppass = "FTPPASS"

$command = "/usr/local/psa/bin/subscription --create " . $domain . " -owner admin -service-plan 'Default Domain' -ip " . $server . " -login " . $ftpuser . " -passwd '" . $ftppass . "'";
$cmd_string = "ssh -p ".$port." ".$username."@".$server." ".$command;
exec($cmd_string, $output);
echo $command;
echo $output;
```

Using uptime as a command works fine, and taking the exact output of the $command and manually pasting it also works fine with a usual output of `SUCCESS: Creation of domain DOMAIN completed` - However when running this, it simply outputs 'Array', with no contents. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

[PHP manual' page about exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is clear about it :

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().

It returns an array filled with each lines of the exec call.

So in your case, you should use :

```
echo $output[0]; // The first and only line
```

Comment: output[0] outputs nothing, no success, no error, just blank - I've used this structure before to retrieve output arrays, and a standard output without specifying line returns each line of the array.

Comment: @Dabien Then just try to `var_dump($output)` and see its structure. It IS an array, as you told it outputs 'Array', maybe there is an extra line break before messing it up so it's `$output[1]`

Comment: var_dump($output) sends out 'array(0) { }' - I'm aware it's an array, I just mean that echoing $output would have shown each line anyway.

Comment: @Dabien Well, no, `echo` on an array won't show the content, never. `print_r` or `var_dump` would, that's why I asked you to do it. Nevermind, you said that running `$command` directly works, what about `$cmd_string` ?

Comment: You're right, my mistake on array printing - I'm still new to PHP and was thinking of something completely different. If I echo the $cmd_string (ssh -p 22 root@IPADDRESS /usr/local/psa/bin/subscription --create DOMAIN -owner admin -service-plan 'Default Domain' -ip IPADDRESS -login FTPUSER -passwd 'FTPPASS'), I can paste it directly into the server console, whilst logged in as the web user (www-data in this case) and it will work perfectly. I can also change the $command to 'uptime' within the php, and echo output[0] will echo out the uptime perfectly.

Comment: @Dabien I don't have any more help in my pocket for you here then. :(